# Best way to keep dynamic database fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, redis, database

I want to build a system where an admin can create forms with the program and users enter data to those forms. Also, admins should be able to enter any field names to their forms, even selectable multiple choice questions.
Only answer I can come up with is creating a huge text block for every form type generated and storing form fields, names, choices, etc serializing them from an array or object.
I would keep the users answers in serialized arrays in another text block, assigning each one with their positions in arrays.

Is there a better approach for this problem?

Comment: i started to get annoyed by this idiotic standard Q&A format stuff. I am sorry but i needed this information from someone who has at least some experience about this stuff, and people helped me if you may just scroll a little bit down. There were no unnecessary discussion about which is better and others sucks. Also, this might be the point where one of the answerers might say 'don't do that with database, here is a better way'. And it is important for me too. I think this nazi like answer closing is the reason S.O. will start falling. Don't break a great community like sun did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [EAV data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) may suit your purposes here. Just be aware that you'll pay for the flexibility with some downsides, such as lack of referential integrity and long queries to retrieve data (every attribute you want to return requires another JOIN).

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can go on this. Since you're working with a relational database, one option is to look at the [Entity-Attribute-Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). In effect, this approach switches your data structure from a predefined schema (columns) into rows. There are many downsides to this flexibility, and you often end up building a bunch of views to present some of this "rotated" data in the form of a more traditional table.

Some relational databases provide noSQL-type features, so you might find a solution down that road. PostgreSQL, for example, has the [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html) type, which allows you to store sets of key-value pairs in a single value. I realize you didn't mention PostgreSQL in your question, but just so you're aware of what's out there, they're also working on a native JSON datatype and function suite for 9.2. Combined with functional indexes, this could provide some interesting relational/noSQL hybrid possibilities without something like Redis or MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a table in the database called something like "Fields"?  Each field has a type and text.  Then also have a table called options, which contains different a text field for the options as well as a fk pointing back to the "fields" table.  There could also be a form table which the fields table has an fk to.  In the code for the app you may then look at a field and determine if you need to fetch an option.  This is a relational database approach.  Some of the object databases like Mongo may handle this much better.

To summarize:

Table: Form
Column: Form_ID PK

Table: Field
Column: Field_ID PK
Column: Text
Column: Type
Column: Form_ID (FK)

Table: Options
Column: Option_ID
Column: Text
Column: Field_ID (FK)